# Behaviour of Callable and Prepared Statements in an app server

Tags: oracle, jdbc, database-connection

CallableStatement and PreparedStatements are precompiled. Are they done with respect to a connection? I mean, lets assume there are some 100 connection objects residing in a connection pool of an app server. There's a class that uses Callable and PreparedStatements. Lets say the method that is used for that is :

```
public  void invokePreparedAndCallableStatements(){  
  //Fetches connection from pool  
  Connection con = getConnectionFromPool();
  CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall(.....);
  cs.register...(...);
  cs.execute();
  ...
  ...
  PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(...);
  st.setXXX(..);
  st.executeUpdate();
  ...
 }
```

Now when the method is called for the first time, a connection is fetched from pool and the request is processed. The Callable and Prepared Statements are compiled. When the method is called another 99 times, each time a different connection is fetched from the pool, then - will the statements be complied for each connection ?
What will be the most optimal way to use statements in this context ? I can't make them (con.prepareCall() or con.prepareStatement()) static because connection isn't static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is actually compiled and stored in the shared pool of the database.  Any number of connections using that same code will benefit from the cache.  The compiled code is kept as long as the memory limits allow.

Comment: Thanks JOTN. Is there any way the same PL/SQL procedure has multiple compiled versions for the same code ?

Answer (score 0):

The statements will be precompiled. Pooling will be based on your specified parameters.

Note: If you are using JDBC 3.0, you can also pool your PreparedStatements. Reference: [What's new in JDBC 3.0](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jdbcnew/)